# How to access Windows dialog styles when using WIN32

Tags: winapi, mfc, dialog

We're using Visual Studio 2019 and creating old win32 style 'bevelled' dialogs. We're not using  MFC. What is the minimum I need to change or add to get the new visual styles ? We have been editing the resource.h and .rc file by hand, but now have it working through the Visual Studio resource editor, and it looks much more modern when testing through there.

Can I just access the new styles in code ?

Do I need to add something to the manifest, as that seems to be overwritten as part of the build.

Then can we use the "movingtype" and "sizingtype" attributes ?  Currently I'm positioning them in code.

Comment: Hard to follow what problem you are *actually* trying to solve here. But you're probably just looking to [enable Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview).

Comment: Yes, thanks, we just found it. All we need is the pragma line in code 

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")